# Rotating a line defined by two points in 3D

Tags: math, vector, geometry

I have edited this question for additional clarity and because of some of the answers below.

I have an electromagnetic motion tracker which tracks a sensor and gives me a point in global space (X, Y, Z). It also tracks the rotation of the sensor and gives Euler angles (Yaw, Pitch, Roll).

The sensor is attached to a rigid body on a baseball cap which sits on the head of a person. However, I wish to track the position of a specific facial feature (nose for example) which I infer from the motion tracker sensor's position and orientation.

I have estimated the spatial offset between the motion tracker and the facial features I want to track. I have done this by simply measuring the offset along the X, Y and Z axis.

Based on a previous answer to this question, I have composed a rotation matrix from the euler angles given to me by the motion tracker. However, I am stuck with how I should use this rotation matrix, the position of the sensor in global space and the spatial offset between that sensor and the nose to give me the position of the nose in global space.

Comment: Sorry but this appears to be off-topic.  I see you already asked the same question on math.stackexchange.com, I would recommend waiting for an answer there.

Comment: OK, fair comment. I've deleted the post from there as math.stackexchange has not attracted a single response in well over a week.

Comment: It's unclear where the angles come in: from the problem definition it looks like there are only 6 variables in the state of the problem (2x3 coordinates) but then later in the question it looks like there is more state in the form of angles which is also attributed to the point. What does "a single recorded position and rotation of p1" mean? p1 was only p1(x1,y1,z1) so cannot have an angle.

Comment: The formulation is indeed is somewhat unclear; if the current position of `p1` can be determined and the only information about `p2` is that the distance `d` to `p2` is fixed, there are infinitely many choices for `p2`, namely the surface of s sphere with center `p1` and radius `d`.

Comment: I have updated my question so that it is more clear. I apologise for the confusion in my original (hastily written) question.

Comment: I think you just need to know what to google for: the clue is that the device with its offset and angles forms a new coordinate system in which the nose is fixed. You know the coordinates of the nose in this coordinate system and you want to get it in the outer/world coordinate system. To to this you need the *transform* that converts between the two coordinate systems. This can be done with a 4x4 linear transform matrix, or by using quaternions. You need to be careful because you have so called Euler angles, which are tricky.  Basically `nose_world = matrix * nose_device`

Comment: Are you comfortable with matrix multiplication?

Comment: See [euler angles to rotation matrix transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

The sensor will give you a rotation matrix (via the Euler angles) and a position (which should be that of the center of rotation).

Whatever item is rigidly fastened to the sensor, such as the nose, will undergo the same motion. Then knowing the relative coordinates of the nose and the sensor, you get the relation

```
Q = R.q + P
```

where `R` is the rotation matrix, `P` the position vector of the sensor and `q` the relative coordinates of the nose.

Note that the relation between the rotation matrix and the angles can be computed using one of these formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix. (You will need to read the article carefully to make sure which your cases is among the 12 possibilities.)

In principle, you determine `R` and `P` from the readings of the sensor, but you are missing the coordinates `q`. There are several approaches:

1. you determine those coordinates explicitly by measuring the distances along virtual axes located at the rotation center and properly aligned.
2. you determine the absolute coordinates `Q` of the nose corresponding to known `R` and `P`; then `q` is given by `R'(Q - P)` where `R'` denotes the transpose of `R` (which is also its inverse). To obtain `Q`, you can just move the sensor center to the nose without moving the head.